# How to Remove Extension Advertisments

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, adminnotification

A couple of extensions showings their advertisements in magento notification section of the Magento admin.
[image]

How do I stop the extensions from showing up in the notifications permanently

Answer (score 2):

Extensions which show custom admin notifications have something similar like the following part in their `config.xml`:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>preDispatch</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

In the related observer, they do something like this:

```
public function preDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $feedModel  = Mage::getModel('namespace_module/feed');
    $feedModel->checkUpdate();
}
```

In order to disable the check for new updates of such a specific extension `Namespace_Module`, you can create an extension which depends (!) on `Namespace_Module` with the following entry in the `config.xml`:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <type>disabled</type>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

This will disable the observer and therefore the check for new updates, so that no more updates will be shown in the future. Note that already fetched updates from this extension will still be shown since they are stored in the `adminnotification_inbox` DB table once they have been fetched.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in the extension admin layout file for something like this:

```
<reference name="notifications">
```

If there is something like that, just comment out the `reference` tag.
If you don't find it, then it's probably done the way Simon explained it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#messages, .messages {
display: none;
}
```

Add this to
`magentoroot/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css`

I don't know if this is safe as it hides ALL admin messages. 
For the extensions individually you can see if there is a specific selector added to the element to target via css.

If not, you may need to inspect each offending extension in order to override the logic which is generating the message.

Comment: Isn't it hide all notifications including core magento notifications?

Comment: That's the reason for my disclaimer. Obviously this is less than ideal but since OP doesn't tell us any details about extensions in order to provide more specific answer, this is all I can give.